# How to get the path in string form of System.Windows.Controls.Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, path

I want to get the path as string of WPF image and give it as an argument to the Bitmap. I need the path in string from.
I have WPF Image with variable image
I have

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="img1.png"></Image>

Bitmap bt=new Bitmap("path of WPF image??");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly create a BitmapImage in XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="image">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="img1.png"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Now you can access the BitmapImage's Source property in code like this:

```
var bitmapImage = (BitmapImage)image.Source;
var uriSource = bitmapImage.UriSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `ToString`:

```
image.Source.ToString();
```

Note, that this won't work with *any* [`ImageSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) descendant, but in the case, when you're setting URI for image source, it will work.